# What is the font used in poster?

Tags: fonts, print-design, typography, font-identification, font-recommendation

I have been working on a typography project and wanted to find a [font](https://www.etsy.com/il-en/listing/679552202/typography-print-black-and-white-prints) which I wanted to use.

I have tried all the methods finding fonts using images online like [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/)  But I couldn't find even similar kind.

[image: poster]

Can you please Help me find [this](https://www.etsy.com/il-en/listing/679552202/typography-print-black-and-white-prints) font?

Comment: have you thought about asking the creator/seller?

Comment: Where did you found this image ? If it's in somewhere like behance you can ask to the creator if you know who is it. If you found it directly on internet, do you have a link ?

Comment: Actually, What the Font does find something similar. The site suggests Silk Serif Condensed Bold, but it's probably the uncondensed bold version shown here: https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/silktype/silk-serif/bold/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it may be this one.

[image]

Either 'Silk-serif Semi-Bold'
https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/silktype/silk-serif/semi-bold/

or 'Silk-serif Medium'
https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/silktype/silk-serif/medium/

It looks more like the Semi Bold.

Comment: Exactly the same! Thanks